# ASP.net label getting value in code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, code-behind

Hey all i am trying to get the value from the label here in my code:

```
<div id="chkHaz" data-checked="no">
   <asp:Label ID="lblchkHaz" runat="server" Text="no" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Image ID="check_chkHaz" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/chkOFF.png" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</div>
```

I set it depending on if the user has "checked" it or not via JQuery:

```
$("#chkHaz").click(function (input) {
   if ($(this).attr("data-checked") == "no") {
      $('#check_' + $(this).attr('id')).attr("src", "/images/chkON.png");
      $(this).attr("data-checked", "yes");
      $('#lbl' + $(this).attr('id')).attr("text", "yes");
      $('#lbl' + $(this).attr('id')).html("yes");
   } else {
      $('#check_' + $(this).attr('id')).attr("src", "/images/chkOFF.png");
      $(this).attr("data-checked", "no");
      $('#lbl' + $(this).attr('id')).attr("text", "no");
      $('#lbl' + $(this).attr('id')).html("no");
   }
});
```

However, when i go to check it via code behind:

```
Dim strChkHaz As String = lblchkHaz.text & ""
```

It always is **"no"** even though i **KNOW** that it changes the **HTML value** of **"no"** to **"yes"** and the **"text"** from **"no"** to **"yes"**

[image]

changes to...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the .aspx file add

```
<asp:HiddenField runat=server ID="..." />
```

2) In JS find that hidden field and update it at the same time when you are changing the label.

3) Now in the code-behin read the .Value property from the hidden field instead of looking at the label text.

Comment: instead of **asp:Hidden** should it not be **asp:HiddenField**?

Comment: Worked fine after adding that instead of the label. Thanks Knahis!

Answer (score 2):

Label values are not posted back you have to use hidden field. You can use labels to show values on client browser but to send the values on postback you need to use hidden field.

You can use input, type="hidden" or asp:hidden field to retrieve the value of label.

**In html**

```
<input type="hidden" runat=server ID="hdnForLabel" />
```

**In jquery**

```
$('<%= hdnForLabel %>').value = "some value";
```

**In Code behind**

```
string strLabelVal = hdnForLabel.Value;
```

Comment: The jQuery part should be: $('#<%= hdnForLabel.ClientID %>').val("some value");

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your selectors are wrong on the first place . When `runat="server"` is applied to an ASP.NET control  the id is prepended with the container . So your id will not look the same as that in HTML.. So in such cases you need to use Attribute starts with or attribute has selector

```
$('#check_' + $(this).attr('id'))
```

Has to be

```
$('[id*="check_' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]')
```